# jQuery: Which Element Triggered Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some thumbnails that I animate a border onto when moused over.
I use `hover()` to assign the functions when `document.ready()` is called. What I'd like is a way to disable this animation effect on the image that the user has clicked on. It has a different class. So, I was planning on doing this by making the animate function include a check to see if the thumb in question had this other class. If not, proceed; if so, do nothing. But to do that I'd need to know which thumbnail (they have unique IDs) triggered the function. Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a `live` handler that excludes the class by writing

```
$('selector:not(.someClass)').live({
    mouseenter: function() {

    }, 
    mouseleave: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, all it took was a live handler on the class for the usual, non-chosen thumbs. Thanks for the idea/inspiration!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.thumbs').hover(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) return;
      //animate here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [target](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target) element of the event, like this:

```
$(".foo").hover(function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id);
    alert(e.target.tagName);
    $(e.target).find(".blahblah").hide();
    // etc.
}, function(e) {
   ...
});
```